# Android Studio Packet Parsing issue .apk

Tags: android, android-studio, build, apk

Ive build an all of my Android Project for School, and cant find a solution for it online. The releases  apk was installing normally on the emulator, but cant get it to work on a real android Device. I wonder which step i did wrong or in which file i have to look closer to fix this issue. Maybe i did something very wrong in the Building Process.I used the grandle build for a  Single apk which was fully signed. Any Suggestion where i should look closer into? I Start to think maybe it has something to do with the Manifest.xml, might be there a Problem?

[image]

Comment: How are you installing in your phone ? if it is not from play store make sure you have turned on “Allow App installation from other sources”

Comment: I put the .apk file in my Storage und go through a File Explorer to the file and Click on it

Comment: Do you have this permission enabled "Install from unknown sources"?

Comment: Run "adb logcat" with the device connected on USB then try to find the error from the PackageManager.

Comment: allowing installing from other app sources, did not work. I will try taht with logcat now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following properties in your build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Now generate APK again and send me the result.

Comment: i'll try it now And will send oyu the results.